# Font resize when Ctrl+ or Ctrl-

Tags: jquery, html, css

While I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>, I want to maintain the font size as it is. It should not be made bigger or smaller. How to achieve this?

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: this is the browser's function, I don't think you can change the browser's behavior. I guess user can change that behavior via some browser's settings.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar What would you show when you have no idea on this topic ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704646/how-do-prevent-text-size-increase-on-html-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any pure css solution.

And there's no clean way to get the current zoom level.

A solution might be to compute it from the changes in the size of the window.

Here's a simple solution (this one not able to differentiate a zoom from a manual resizing) :

```
var initialWidth = window.innerWidth,
    initialFontSize = 20;   
window.onresize=function(){
  document.getElementById('notresized').style.fontSize = (initialFontSize*window.innerWidth/initialWidth |0)+'px';
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/jalel/2/)

EDIT : contrary to what I initially thought, I'm not able to discern from a *real* resize event, which makes this solution rarely usable.

**Bottom Line :** What you try to do is difficult to achieve and the reason is you probably shouldn't. This would be terrible for usability (for example, some people can't read small characters).

Answer (score 0):

Read about [text-size-adjust](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust).

Setting `text-size-adjust: none` will automatically prevent adjusting font size when zooming. Since it is not a standard property you must use it with prefixes :

1. -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
2. -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
3. -ms-text-size-adjust: none;

Comment: This only work on some mobiles. Not on desktop. And it's highly experimental.

Comment: EDITED. I made a mistake. `text-size-adjust` is what you need.

Comment: This is a nice thing you have shared. But I am not able to get it working,

Comment: Please give a fiddle and the say which browser you are using.

Comment: @dystroy You were right. I misunderstanded what he asked. I thought he is asking how to automatically adjust font size. However i edited my answer, it is achievable by `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none`

Answer (score 0):

There is a way given to disable the scroll for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + mouse scroll , using this and modifying the solution for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>

1.Download AutoHotKey software 
2.In the AutoHotkey.ahk file, add these

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
{
^NumpadAdd (+)::return 
^NumpadSub (-)::return
#MaxHotkeysPerInterval 1000
}
```

Reference:- https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/-rtDLZmN9bk/5pJYksjrvQUJ

Comment: this solution wouldn't work if it's for other users. I think that the questioner wants to implement it in his webpage.