# Keeping text size the same on zooming

Tags: html, css

I want to make a line on the top of the page that can't be zoomed. Neither the line, nor the text contained in it. The main problem is the text. Whenever I zoom in my browser, the line stays the same height, but the text in it grows, and goes out from the line.

Is there any css command what I can use?

I've already tried `font-size-adjust: none;` and `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;` but none of them worked.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9F5m/3/) what I've tried to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable zoom on a div, but allow zoom on the page (an alternate div)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886763/disable-zoom-on-a-div-but-allow-zoom-on-the-page-an-alternate-div)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do prevent text size increase on html/css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704646/how-do-prevent-text-size-increase-on-html-css)

Comment: on the first link of possible duplicate is about how to make text scale to a div's width, on the second link, they use the `-webkit-text-size-adjust` command, neither of those works for me

Comment: Previous posts do not really provide a way to overcome zooming issues.  Whoever thumbed this post down should thumb it back up!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You actually can get around zooming by using viewport units.  Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TnY3L/.  Also, I did my personal website using viewport units and no zooming works on it when you use Ctrl + or Ctrl - keys (see http://www.functionalcss.com/).  Older browsers do not support vw, vh, vmin, vmax.  I got around it by using a polyfill: http://html5polyfill.com/

HTML:

```
<div id = "header">This is a header</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 10vh;
    line-height: 10vh;
    font-size: 5vh;
    text-align: center;
}
```