# Trouble with CSS label and box overlapping when zooming text only

Tags: html, css

I have a Label "Description" and to the right is a textbox for userinput. They have a decent distance apart in normal view. However, when I zoom in to the max using "zoom text only" on firefox the textbox overlaps the word (a few letters). I tried to use Float:left but that didn't work. Padding *could* work but it makes the normal view really awkward with the spacing. I guess ultimately I want the Word "Description" to move to the left while zooming in so there's no overlap. Thanks!

Comment: for the Label the css is:
.label{
   padding-top 7px;
   margin-top: 0;
   margin-bottom: 0;
}

the css for the textbox is:
.input-box {
   position: relative;
   display:table;
   border-collapse: separate;
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do prevent text size increase on html/css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704646/how-do-prevent-text-size-increase-on-html-css)