# Is it important to have relative units to ensure Section 508 / WCAG 2.0 Level AA compatibility?

Tags: html, css, accessibility, section508, wcag2.0

I have all my font sizes defined in pixels, e.g.

```
body {
  font-size: 14px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 42px;
}
```

One of the online Section 508 / WCAG 2.0 Level AA compatibility checkers advised me to replace it with relative units to make it accessible to people who increased their font size via browser. Is that a real requirement to follow? I doubt because none of the other online checkers advised me so (although I do understand that it's not always possible to test it automatically).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, 508 does not *specifically require* that font size be adjustable, but experts *expressly recommend* allowing font resize. Nielson [says](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/let-users-control-font-size/):

> **Let Users Control Font Size**: Tiny text tyrannizes users by dramatically reducing task throughput. IE4 had a great UI that let users easily change font sizes; let's get this design back in the next generation of browsers.

On this line, [Section 508 § 1194.21(g)](https://www.section508.gov/content/learn/standards/quick-reference-guide#1194.21g) does state:

> Applications shall not override user selected contrast and color selections and other individual display attributes

which includes font size and is compatible with the [WCAG text resize success criterion](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-scale.html) that:

> The author's responsibility is to create Web content that does not prevent the user agent from scaling the content effectively

So long as you're not forbidding text resizing (like using images of text or using the [`text-resize-adjust` CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11913314/2908724)), you're good. But, at the end of the day, the use of [relative font size](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) provides for a better experience resizing text, which includes not just size of the font but attributes like line wrapping.

For these reasons, I'd consider relative font sizes important for *aesthetics* but not important for *accessibility*.

Comment: This was mostly an issue in older (<= v6 IIRC) of Internet Explorer which would not allow the resizing of text when font-size was specified in px. Not really an issue in modern browsers.

Comment: @steveax I'm unsure what you're arguing. Perhaps I was unclear? Someone can build a site that prevents text resizing (see my edit with examples), which violates section 508. On the other hand, someone can build a site that takes maximum advantage of browser font resize capability (like viewport sized typography as I linked) which embraces 508 and WCAG.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But basically, since you can adjust your font size with Ctrl + / Ctrl - (as Tiffany stated above) regardless if its font size is defined in relative or fixed units, I seem to be allowed to use both, right?

Comment: @Deka87 Yes, you are allowed to use both. However, you will get better typographic aesthetic using viewport relative font sizes. Specifically check out the link to css-tricks with demo and discussion: https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/ For these reasons, I'd consider relative font sizes *important for aesthetics* but not important for accessibility.

Comment: @bishop, thanks for the link. I got your point. My fav is to combine px and rem, however this seems too tricky for 508 compliant projects.

Comment: bishop, not really arguing, just noting that in the past, using px for font-size would prevent IE users from resizing text. Not an issue in modern browsers.

Answer (score 3):

W3C lists "Resizing text" as one of the requirements, but it states that the user must be able to increase the size of the text on a page without the use assistive technology, like the screen magnifier program.  To test this, you can press CTRL-+ or command-+ on the affected pages, and if the text increases in size, then your content meets the requirement.  To read more, check out: [Understanding SC 1.4.4, resize text](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-scale.html).

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful too.

Answer (score 2):

**"px" unit are defined as "css pixels". They already are "relative units"**

See https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html

> The px unit is the magic unit of CSS. It is not related to the current font and usually not relatated to physical centimeters or inches either.

So the tool you are using is not accurate or outdated as it's no longer a problem for modern browsers.

You can also adopt the method indicated in the above linked document:

> But for font sizes it is even better to use em. The idea is (1) to not set the font size of the BODY element (in HTML), but use the default size of the device, because that is a size that the reader can comfortably read; and (2) express font sizes of other elements in em

Comment: Thanks, Adam. The tool did note that "px" units can be considered as relative units, thought it didn't recommend to use them anyway. The rest of your answer makes sense too though.